# Ways to return column names from Sqlite database in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sqlite

What are the possible ways and the best ways to return column names of a table in a Sqlite database in MATLAB? JDBC driver is used. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query sqlite this: `PRAGMA table_info(name_of_your_table);`. It will give you information of all columns.

Example:

```
% Assuming your JDBC driver is already added to your java path

% create connection to database file
conn = database('', '', '', 'org.sqlite.JDBC', 'jdbc:sqlite:C:\your_db.sqlite');

cursor = exec(conn, 'PRAGMA table_info(name_of_your_table);');
cursor = fetch(cursor);
```

To output the column names, it is little different depending on used `DataReturnFormat` ([Matlab Documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/setdbprefs.html#bt6fwwn-2))

- Cellarray (default)

```matlab
% When DataReturnFormat is cellarray
cursor.Data(:,2) % returns table column names
```

- table, dataset or structure

```matlab
% When DataReturnFormat is table, dataset or structure
cursor.Data.name
```